# Centering an absolute div vertically and horizontally on an image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a `div` inside an image. I'm not sure what's wrong here. I'm currently confused with positioning and aligning as well and I may need to work on it as well. Thanks for your input in advance guys.

```css
.template-banner{
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0;
}
.template-banner-wrpr{
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
}

.template-banner-img {
 content: url("../img/template-banner.jpg");
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
}
.tbanner-reg-wrpr1{
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
}
.tbanner-reg-wrpr{
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 right: -50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 500px;
}
.tbanner-reg-desc-wrpr{
 width: 680px;
 float: left;
 height: 285px;
}

.tbanner-reg-input{
 width: 270px;
 float: left;
 background-color: rgb(247,247,247);
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 10px 25px 25px 25px;
 height: 250px;
}
.tbanner-reg-input p{
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.tbanner-loginb{
 background-color: #ff3b30;
 border: solid #ff3b30 1px ;
 border-color: #ff3b30;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.tbanner-regemail, .tbanner-regpsw, .tbanner-regpnumber, .tbanner-loginb {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 5px 0px 10px 0px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-style: line;
 border-color: rgb(249,249,249);
}


.template-features {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgb(246,244,245);
}
```

```html
<div class="template-banner">
 <div class="template-banner-wrpr1"><img class="template-banner-img"></div>
 <div class="tbanner-reg-wrpr">
  
   <div class="tbanner-reg-desc-wrpr">
   <h3 p id="tbanner-reg-desc-title">Heading Division 1</h3>
   <p id="tbanner-reg-desc-info">Text hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText here</p>
   </div>
   <div class="tbanner-reg-input"><p>Registration/Image</p>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Your work email" name="wemail" class="tbanner-regemail">
   <input type="password" placeholder="Your Password" name="psw" class="tbanner-regpsw">
   <input type="text" placeholder="090-1234-5678" name="pnumber" class="tbanner-regpnumber">
   <input type="submit" name="gstarted" value="Signup" class="tbanner-loginb">
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIxPY.png)

Comment: I would definitely look into flexbox or even css grid, much easier than using floats to create these kind of layouts, there are heaps of good tutorials on flexbox that are super easy to follow and will definitely help you out

Answer (score 3):

Absolute positioning at 50% from the top and left uses 50% of the container to position the child. A transform translating the element -50% from the top and left will use 50% of the elements own dimensions and you get a centered element.

The two column layout is easy to achieve with inline-block, grid, flexbox, or a simple float which requires the least css.

```css
.container {
  background-image: url(http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4615/24977545657_f984bbaec2_b.jpg);
  height: 400px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.content-wrapper {
  min-height: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 80%;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.content-wrapper div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
}

.left-column {
border: 5px solid orange;
}
.right-column {
border: 5px solid cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="left-column"></div>
    <div class="right-column"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Best solution :)

Comment: Thank you! I think I was on the same path the only difference is I didn't make my image as a background inside the contained but it was separated on a different div.

Answer (score 0):

Here its my code to fix your issue

I was changed `top` and `left` of `tbanner-reg-wrpr`
and add `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

And `.template-banner` need to change `position` to `relative`

```css
.template-banner{
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.template-banner-wrpr{
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
}

.template-banner-img {
 content: url("http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/");
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
}
.tbanner-reg-wrpr1{
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
}
.tbanner-reg-wrpr{
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #0000006b;
}
.tbanner-reg-desc-wrpr{
 width: 200px;
 float: left;
 height: 285px;
}

.tbanner-reg-input{
 width: 270px;
 float: left;
 background-color: rgb(247,247,247);
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 10px 25px 25px 25px;
 height: 250px;
}
.tbanner-reg-input p{
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.tbanner-loginb{
 background-color: #ff3b30;
 border: solid #ff3b30 1px ;
 border-color: #ff3b30;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.tbanner-regemail, .tbanner-regpsw, .tbanner-regpnumber, .tbanner-loginb {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 5px 0px 10px 0px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-style: line;
 border-color: rgb(249,249,249);
}


.template-features {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgb(246,244,245);
}
```

```html
<div class="template-banner">
 <div class="template-banner-wrpr1"><img class="template-banner-img"></div>
 <div class="tbanner-reg-wrpr">
  
   <div class="tbanner-reg-desc-wrpr">
   <h3 p id="tbanner-reg-desc-title">Heading Division 1</h3>
   <p id="tbanner-reg-desc-info">Text hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText hereText here</p>
   </div>
   <div class="tbanner-reg-input"><p>Registration/Image</p>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Your work email" name="wemail" class="tbanner-regemail">
   <input type="password" placeholder="Your Password" name="psw" class="tbanner-regpsw">
   <input type="text" placeholder="090-1234-5678" name="pnumber" class="tbanner-regpnumber">
   <input type="submit" name="gstarted" value="Signup" class="tbanner-loginb">
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/z9pe5aq5/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
     <div class="left"></div>
     <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and css

```
.wrapper{border:1px solid red;width:100%;height:200px;display:flex;justify-content:center}
.content{width:200px;border:1px solid red;margin:20px;display:block;display:flex;justify-content:center}
.left{border:1px solid green;width:40%;display:inline-block}
.right{border:1px solid yellow;width:40%;display:inline-block}
```

I using flex box,